# How can I prevent app redirects when opening slack links and always open them in the browser?

Tags: slack

I want this on Firefox, the answers I found are only for Chrome.

When I open Slack links from Firefox, I get "You will be redirected in a few moments.
Don’t have the app yet? Download Slack for Desktop. You can also open this link in your browser." I want that to be skipped and always open in the browser

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since
[Firefox users may import Chrome extensions now](https://www.ghacks.net/2023/08/23/firefox-users-may-import-chrome-extensions-now/),
you may follow this article in order to install in Firefox the Chrome
extension of
[Open Slack in Browser, not App](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/open-slack-in-browser-not/jkgehijlkoolgcjifalbiicaomkngakb):

> This extension automatically redirect to the slack link with your
> browser, not open slack app. Nothing more, nothing less.
>
> You don't have to download and install slack app in your machine once
> you install this extension. You can continue to use slack through a
> Chrome browser.

[image]

Comment: All the Chrome-specific stuff I found didn't work either, or was even more specific to Windows, so thanks.
It's absolutely ridiculous that we would have to rely on browser extensions to disable this extremely obnoxious behaviour, but here we are…